# como tirar duplicatas de uma lista com dicionários

Tags: python

eu tenho essa entrada .txt:

```
Brasil#ouro#futebol feminino
Argentina#bronze#basquete masculino
Brasil#prata#futebol masculino
Argentina#prata#tênis masculino
Brasil#prata#volei feminino
China#ouro#tênis de mesa masculino
Japão#ouro#judô feminino -50 kg
```

e preciso transforma-lá em:

```
(1, 2, 0,'Brasil')
(1, 0, 0,'Japão')
(1, 0, 0,'China')
(0, 1, 1,'Argentina')
```

meu código ta assim:

```
lista = []

for linha in arquivo:
    n = linha.split("#")
    dados = {"pais": n[0], "ouro": 0, "prata": 0, "bronze": 0, "modalidade": n[2].rstrip("\n")}

    if n[1] == "ouro":
        dados["ouro"] = dados["ouro"] + 1
    elif n[1] == "prata":
        dados["prata"] = dados["prata"] + 1
    elif n[1] == "bronze":
        dados["bronze"] = dados["bronze"] + 1
    if dados["pais"] not in lista:
        lista.append(dados)


print(lista)

return None
```

e ele retorna isso:

```
 [{'pais': 'Brasil', 'ouro': 1, 'prata': 0, 'bronze': 0, 'modalidade': 'futebol feminino'}, {'pais': 'Argentina', 'ouro': 0, 'prata': 0, 'bronze': 1, 'modalidade': 'basquete masculino'}, {'pais': 'Brasil', 'ouro': 0, 'prata': 1, 'bronze': 0, 'modalidade': 'futebol masculino'}, {'pais': 'Argentina', 'ouro': 0, 'prata': 1, 'bronze': 0, 'modalidade': 'tênis masculino'}, {'pais': 'Brasil', 'ouro': 0, 'prata': 1, 'bronze': 0, 'modalidade': 'volei feminino'}, {'pais': 'China', 'ouro': 1, 'prata': 0, 'bronze': 0, 'modalidade': 'tênis de mesa masculino'}, {'pais': 'Japão', 'ouro': 1, 'prata': 0, 'bronze': 0, 'modalidade': 'judô feminino -50 kg'}]
```

como eu somo todas as medalhas de ouro, prata e bronze(separadamente) de um pais?; como eu retiro as duplicadas de "pais", mas somo as medalhas?
Obs: proibido uso de métodos, import, etc.
e me desculpem pela burrice, mas já tentando a horas e to moscando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver é fazer com que o nome do país seja ele próprio a chave do dicionário. E o valor deste pode ser outro dicionário contendo a quantidade de medalhas.

Assim, é possível obter o total, e depois você converte esses dados para a lista de tuplas:

```
dados = {}
with open('entrada.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        pais, medalha, modalidade = linha.split('#')
        if pais not in dados: # país ainda não está no dicionário
            dados[pais] = {} # cria um dicionário de medalhas vazio
        dados[pais][medalha] = dados[pais].get(medalha, 0) + 1 # soma a quantidade de medalhas

# dicionário estará assim:
# {'Brasil': {'ouro': 1, 'prata': 2}, 'Argentina': {'bronze': 1, 'prata': 1}, 'China': {'ouro': 1}, 'Japão': {'ouro': 1}}
print(dados)

# cria a lista de tuplas
lista = []
for pais, medalhas in dados.items():
    lista.append((medalhas.get('ouro', 0), medalhas.get('prata', 0), medalhas.get('bronze', 0), pais))

print(lista) # [(1, 2, 0, 'Brasil'), (0, 1, 1, 'Argentina'), (1, 0, 0, 'China'), (1, 0, 0, 'Japão')]
```

A ideia é que o dicionário `dados` fique assim:

```
{
    'Brasil':
    {
        'ouro': 1,
        'prata': 2
    },
    'Argentina':
    {
        'bronze': 1,
        'prata': 1
    },
    'China':
    {
        'ouro': 1
    },
    'Japão':
    {
        'ouro': 1
    }
}
```

Ou seja, cada nome de país aponta para outro dicionário, contendo a quantidade de medalhas.

Com isso, basta percorrer este dicionário e cria a lista de tuplas. Ao usar `get('ouro', 0)`, ele retorna zero caso a medalha não exista no respectivo dicionário.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Outra possibilidade é abandonar o uso de [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), para totalizar as medalhas, e em seu lugar utilizar [listas](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) pois tuplas são [imutáveis](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-immutable) e listas não, o que facilita ao criar um totalizador de medalhas em um algoritmo de passagem única por cada item de dado.

Para facilitar a totalização em um algoritmo de passagem única crie uma lista com o `total` de medalhas cada país e um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) como índice para cada um do valores inseridos na lista de totais, onde a chave é o nome do país e o valor é referência para um totalizador de medalhas inserido na lista `total`.

```
total = []   #Lista contendo o total de medalhas de cada país.
paises = {}  #Dicionário de indices para cada país listado em total.

with open('medalhas.txt') as arquivo:
  #Para cada linha no arquivo 'medalhas.txt'...
  for linha in arquivo:
    pais, medalha, modalidade = linha.split('#')    #Separa em seus componente.
    i = 0 if medalha == "ouro" else 1 if medalha == "prata" else 2 #Calcula o índice da medalha.
    #Se o pais em questão ainda não foi indexado...
    if pais not in paises:
      resultado = [0, 0, 0, pais]   #Inicializa um novo totalizador de medalhas.
      resultado[i] = 1              #Contabiliza a primeira medalha.
      total.append(resultado)       #Popula a lista total com o novo totalizador.
      paises[pais] = resultado      #Cria um índice para o novo totalizador.
    else:
      paises[pais][i] = paises[pais][i] + 1         #Atualiza o total de medalhas.
```

Resultando em:

```
>>>print(total)
[[1, 2, 0, 'Brasil'], 
 [0, 1, 1, 'Argentina'], 
 [1, 0, 0, 'China'], 
 [1, 0, 0, 'Japão']]
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/ConstantRaggedAssignments)</sup>